# How to prioritize technical tasks in an early stage company?

Tags: architecture, infrastructure

I recently joined a startup as a developer, they have done a lot so far, and we coming to the day of the launch, when we will leave the stealth mode and go public(not IPO, just launch the product).

Although they have done a good job so far, it is noticeable that some good practices were not followed, and they probably become a technical debt, but it nos clear when they will be a liability, in parallel there are a lot of stuff that must be done for the launch.

I would like to hear from you some of the experiences you had, and if you know any articles, videos or books that discuss this moment of the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the approach should be a long term one. Based on this, as you said, there are additional features and extensions that would have to be added in the future, and you can't halt all of those in order to solve all the technical debt created along the way.

One solution would be either to have a dedicated tooling/infrastructure team which is able to go somewhat in parallel with the development team, in order to improve and optimize certain processes which currently suffer from technical debt (build, testing, deployment) as well as maybe sometime in the future, enforce some sort of best practices over the software engineering methodologies applied within the company (software quality gates, code compliance checks), different metrics which should be met in order to solve some of the technical issues and ensure that anything newly added won't suffer from the same problems as the older features.

A good principle to look forward to would be to think, design and validate a product/feature/technical concept more before actually starting to implement it, so that all corner cases and possible design mistakes are already dealt with before the implementation stage, rather than just implementing it and then adjust it along the way (TL;DR think more before working, so the code can be written better right from the start).